# state difference in time complexities?

Tags: debugging

```
int prime(ll n)
{
    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++){
        if(n%2==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


int prime(ll n)
{
    if(n<2)
        return 0;
    else if(n==2)
        return 1;
    if(n%2==0)
        return 0;
    for(int j=3; j*j<=n; j+=2)
    {
        if(n%j==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

can anyone please tell me the difference between the time complexities of these functions? 
Because using the above function in my code, it gives me wrong answer in codeforces round #142 Div 2 problem. But choosing the second function gives me correct answer. Why ??